# Accessing path variables and request parameters without annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have many rest controllers as following:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/my-endpoint")
public class MyRestController {

    @Override
    @GetMapping(value = "/{type}/{code}", produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyDTO>> query(
        @PathVariable(value = "type") final String type,
        @PathVariable(value = "code") final Integer code,
        @RequestParam(value = "key", required = false) final String key) {

        // ...
    }
```

}

But, how can I have access to both path variables and request parameters inside the query method without using annotations? Moreover, I need to get the path of the endpoint. It'd be like what can be done with Servlets. Something like that (I know that the code below doesn't work):

```
String type = request.getPathVariable("type");
String key = request.getParam("key");
String endpoint = request.getPath(); // endpoint will hold "my-endpoint"
```

I'm new in the Spring world, so I guess the question is very basic. But, I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Controller to this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/my-endpoint")
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{type}/{code}", produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyDTO>> query(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String endpoint = request.getRequestURI();
        String[] data = endpoint.split("/");
        Integer code = Integer.valueOf(data[data.length - 1]);
        String type = data[data.length - 2];
        String key = request.getQueryString().split("=")[1];
        System.out.println(code + "\n" + key + "\n" + type + "\n" + endpoint);
        .....
    }
}
```

Sample Request : `http://localhost:8080/v1/my-endpoint/def/2?key=abc`

Output on console :

```
2
abc
def
/v1/my-endpoint/def/2
```

Added an alternative way through spring :

```
String endpoint = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().toUriString();
String[] data = endpoint.split("/");
Integer code = Integer.valueOf(data[data.length - 1]);
String type = data[data.length - 2];
System.out.println(code + "\n" + type + "\n" + endpoint);
```

Comment: Hi, @Anish. The problem is that I don't have access to the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. The Eclipse doesn't find them on my classpath.

Comment: @tnas Press Ctrl + Shift + O or Command + Shift + O. Eclipse will auto import.

Comment: @tnas add servlet api jar or add server to get support.

Comment: @tnas please add the server to your project.

Comment: @tnas Do you know how to add server runtime on the eclipse for a project ?

Comment: Doesn't Spring offer support to this type of operation without adding a complementary lib?

Comment: @tnas No, it's complicated. That jar is a requirement when you deploy the spring project it will use that jar.

Comment: @tnas Download jar from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api

Comment: I got it... I have to check with the team if I can proceed with adding this lib. I don't understand why Spring complicates so basic operations :(

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative to avoid adding another lib

Comment: @tnas I have updated my answer. I added through spring way.

Comment: thank you! It was exactly what I have been looking for.